# CS-Script - How Can I Run a '.cs' File Like A Standard Windows Executable?

Tags: c#, windows, scripting

I have recently installed [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/), a **scripting system for C#** (as well as VB.NET, C++/CLI and J#).

**CS-Script** allows you to write a program in standard C# syntax (or in other languages supported by CS-Script) and run it without first compiling it to an executable! In this way, CS-Script offers the benefits of Windows Script Host (WSH) and other scripting frameworks and languages.

By default, when you double-click a **.cs** file, CS-Script is configured to to open it with Notepad. Instead, I actually wanted to change this so that double-clicking the **.cs** file would *run* the script. I was able to make this change by running the CS-Script configuration program **css_config.exe**, and under **Open (double-click action)**, selecting **<Run>**.

**Now, a question:** There is one more thing I want to do--I'd like to be able to put a **.cs** file somewhere in my **system path** and run it like any other standard Windows executable. (For example, **.exe**, **.bat** and **.cmd** files.) Is this is possible?

Comment: The author opens many (simple) questions only for answering themself

Comment: @jeb - 'Simple' is in the eye of the beholder. 'Simple' also comes with experience. I think of SO as a vast knowledge base. Not everyone can be an expert in all areas. A well-titled and stated question with one or more straightforward answers is to everyone's benefit. In the end, the cumulative votes on a question and its answers advertise to all the merits of both. Feel free to express your opinion by downvoting as you see fit.

Comment: My comment came automatically from a close vote. My critic is about your questions and answer structure. You ask many questions and then you give directly the answer. This is allowed on SO, but it shouldn't be missused.

Comment: Relevant reading on Meta: [Etiquette for answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/243253). I posted this question because I couldn't find an answer in the CS-Script documentation and I believed others might benefit. (Clearly, though, I have offended at least five people.) Finally, regarding the assertion that I ask many questions: a quick look at my profile would reveal that to be very untrue over the long term. (Though, yes, there were three over the last couple of days.)

Comment: Maybe this question should be moved to superuser??

Comment: @MusuNaji In the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), the article [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states that questions considered acceptable include those that concern: *"software tools commonly used by programmers"*. Under that guideline, I believe this question is on-topic for SO. That said, I think this question would *also* be on topic on SuperUser. And that's OK because there are certain questions that would be considered on topic on more than one site on the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible! You simply need to tell Windows that a **.cs** file is an executable file. To accomplish this, all that you need to do is add the **.cs** file extension to your `PATHEXT` environment variable.

For example, here's what `PATHEXT` looks like on my Windows 7 system after I have appended the **.cs** extension:

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CS
                                                             ^^^^
```

You may also want to eliminate the banner that CS-Script outputs when you run your script. To eliminate the banner, run **css_config.exe**, and under **Open (double-click action)**, add the `/nl` command line option. For example, if you have installed CS-Script at **C:\cs-script**, your modified command line will look like this:

```
"C:\cs-script\cscs.exe" /nl "%1" %*
                        ^^^
```